# Ansible return status

Tags: jboss, ansible

I have an ansible playbook which deploys a jboss eap instance alongside some other things. The playbook runs fine until it gets to the point to start jboss using the provided standalone.sh script. I am using the shell module to start this script and it works fine in that jboss starts however when the task is executed ansible does not return any status message like a changed or OK and just seems to hang.

Is there a way I can force ansible to see this as something which has changed the system state ?

Comment: you can run the playbook in verbose mode `-vvvv`

Comment: Yeah I know that however doesn't really give me enough to go on. The issue is the script being executed does not make any system state changes therefore ansible does not respond back and just hangs

Answer (score 3):

I don't personally use jboss, but this sounds to me like the startup.sh script simply isn't launching jboss in the background, so ansible is simply waiting for it to end and it never does.

There are a few potential ways you can address this.  Given the information in [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/197707?tstart=0&_sscc=t) you might want to try a task like this:

```
- name: start jboss
  shell: nohup standalone.sh > /dev/null
  async: True
  poll: 0
```

The `poll: 0` tells Ansible to 'fire and forget' the command.  If you don't include this then Ansible will kill the process when it returns from the remote server.

Another possibility is to use an init script.  The thread I linked to above points to a location where you should be able to find an init script.  You could install that (and leave it disabled if you don't want jboss to start up when the system reboots), and then simply run it via the service command from Ansible:

```
- name: start jboss
  service: name=jboss state=started
```

Edit: If you're unwilling or unable to use nohup or an init script that puts jboss into the background then another alternative is to make use of [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) if you have that installed and available to you. I regularly do this when invoking long-running commands from Ansible so that I can check back well after the playbook has been run to check on the status of the command:

```
- name: Invoke long running command
  command: /usr/bin/screen -d -m /path/to/my/command
  async: True
  poll: 0
```

This will launch a detached screen session and invoke your command inside it. Ansible will promptly forget about it, leaving the command to run on its own.

Comment: Thanks, however the script IS running and working fine. When its executed via the ansible task it just hangs ( JBoss starts up fine, but the ansible task hangs ). When running the script it dumps a bunch of information to the console, so I think whats happening is that Ansible is not returning any type of status hence keeping the task open... Usually when running a script or a command it will return a OK, Changed etc, depending on whether it has changed the state of the system. In this case because the script just dumps a load of output to the screen there is no state change so to speak.

Comment: You say that the script dumps a bunch of output to the screen.  Does it ever return back to a command prompt without you having to do anything like hit a keystroke?

Comment: nope nothing, its essentially just a script to start JBoss, and it goes through a bunch of xml files checking everything is in place. It takes around 20 seconds or so before it starts up the JVMs etc... I tried setting async to 20 seconds, and this works fine, but it seems to kill the Java ( JBoss ) processes thereafter...

Comment: If it's not returning to a command prompt then it's running in the foreground, so it's just as I outlined in my answer. You need to launch jboss in such a way that it's put into the background, otherwise control will never return to Ansible. It's the same as if you did something like manually invoked `ssh remote-host /path/to/standalone.sh` yourself. The ssh call won't return if standalone.sh is running in the foreground. Ansible is essentially doing exactly the same thing. You either need to rewrite standalone.sh to launch jboss into the background, use nohup, or use an init script.